# What part of speech is it?

Tags: parts-of-speech

*DRIVING in the town centre is banned during the day.
I think they should ban DRIVING in the town centre during the day*

What part of speech is DRIVING in these sentences? Is it a noun?

Answer (score 3):

> *DRIVING in the town centre is banned during the day.*
>
> *I think they should ban DRIVING in the town centre during the day.*

I'd say that "driving" is ambiguous between a verb and a noun, though verb preferred.

Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in *unnecessary/non-essential driving*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, “driving” is a noun here; it refers to *the activity of* driving (generally).

The noun definition of “driving” is:

> the control and operation of a motor vehicle.

Specifically, “driving” in this context is a *gerund*, defined by the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/gerund) as:

> a word ending in "-ing" that is made from a verb and used like a noun

Were I forced to think of “driving” in this context as a verb, I think I would interpret “ban driving” as meaning:

> ban (verb) while driving (verb)

Comment: Note that BillJ's answer is straight from the prestigious CGEL (though it would be helpful if this were made clear, with a section reference, as is recommended on ELU). Any claim conflicting or not totally agreeing with such an authority needs substantive support.

Comment: It isn't straight from GGEL, so there is no section reference to quote. Just my logical analysis, really.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Thanks, I’ve updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.   You only have to ask yourself "what is the subject of the main verb in the sentence.  You have said it is a sentence.  The only candidate for the job is "driving".  So in the sentence, it perform the role of **noun** subject.  It is,  to be more detailed, a 'verbal noun'.

This is a source of much confusion in English.   It can function in other contexts as an adjective.  It is often called a *gerund*, after a part of speech in the inflected language, Latin.  In Latin the *infinitive* pellere would be used.  Modern French has a simple noun, *la conduite*.  So

> La conduite est interdite.

In general, the less inflected the language, the trickier it becomes to speak of 'parts of speech.

*Drive* can serve as the base verb,; as an imperative; as the 1st or 2nd person singular and 1st, 2nd and 3rd person plural of the present tense; as a noun ("Park in our drive" or "the batsman launched a brilliant cover drive" or even "Let's go for a drive.").  By contrast, the French present indicative tense alone has six different 'parts', one for each 'person', singular and plural.

1. Je conduise
2. Tu conduises
3. Elle/il conduit
4. Nous conduisons
5. Vous conduisez
6. Elles/ils conduisent.

English only has two:-

1. I-you-we-you-they drive (all the same termination)
2. He/she drive**s** (the weird survival of inflection in the third person singular.)

So in your context, *drive* serves as a verbal noun, subject of the main verb.

Comment: Clauses can be subjects, too. "Driving" may well be a clause consisting of just a VP with the verb "driving" as head, hence the claim that it's strictly speaking ambigious.

Comment: But lots of different parts of speech and types of phrase can function as subject!